# How to access individual elements from a 2d vector type pointer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, 2d

```cpp
template<class T>
struct Edges{
    T u,v;
    int w;
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    vector<struct Edges<int>> *ptr = new vector<struct Edges<int>>(
        {{1,2,1},{1,3,1}, {2,3,1}}
    );
    
    // access individual elements from the 2d pointer

    return 0;
}
```

How to access the individual elements from the `ptr` pointer? I tried to access it using `ptr[0]->u` but it shows compile time error `base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Edges<int> >’`

Comment: You don't have a 2d array or vector.  You have a 1d array of `Edges`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer to a single `std::vector` object, not an array of `std::vector`s. You are treating that pointer as if it were pointing at an array, which it is not (well, technically, any object can be treated as an array of 1 element).

`ptr[0]` is the same as `*(ptr+0)` ie `*ptr`, thus dereferencing that pointer will access the `std::vector` itself, not its 1st element. If you were to try using a higher index, ie `ptr[1]`, then you would access beyond that single `std::vector`, which is *undefined behavior*.

`std::vector` does not have an `->` operator, which is why `ptr[0]->` fails to compile.

But, even if you were accessing the `std::vector`'s 1st element correctly, `->` would still be wrong to use, since the `std::vector` is not holding `Edge*` pointers for its elements. It is holding actual `Edge` objects, so you would need to use the `.` operator instead to access fields of each `Edge`.

You would need to use the following syntax instead to access individual fields of each `Edge` in the `std::vector` via the pointer:

```cpp
(*ptr)[element_index].field
```

For example:

```cpp
int main(){
    vector<Edges<int>> *ptr = new vector<Edges<int>>(
        {{1,2,1},{1,3,1}, {2,3,1}}
    );
    
    // access individual elements from the vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ptr->size(); ++i)
        cout << (*ptr)[i].u << ' ';

    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/dAYfaf)

But, why are you using `new` like this at all? `std::vector` holds a dynamically allocated array, so there is no need to create the `std::vector` itself dynamically as well. It is unusual to `new` any standard C++ container. For example:

```cpp
int main(){
    vector<Edges<int>> vec(
        {{1,2,1},{1,3,1}, {2,3,1}}
    );
    
    // access individual elements from the vector, eg
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        cout << vec[i].u << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/lhjwKs)